# PHP.В браузере весь текст пишется в одной строке

Tags: php

```
<?php

$n = 1; // integer int

$a = 154.1; // float

$b = "dddddd dd ddddd"; // string

$bool = false; //boolean

$null = null; //null

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump($bool);
var_dump($null);
```

Comment: Надо учить HTML

Comment: `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($a); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Оригинальный текст страницы, полученный браузером, можно так -  кликнуть правой кнопкой мышки на странице и выбрать пункт меню "Исходный код страницы / Просмотр кода страницы / Просмотреть исходный код"

Answer (score 1):

После `echo` надо добавить `<br>`.

**Например:** `echo 'hi, world' . '<br>';`.